# How to know what caused a simple DAG in Apache Airflow to fail?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am new to Apache Airflow.
I wanted to create a simple DAG with a single Task that launches a python script in a virtual environment:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
with DAG("Inference_DAG", 
        start_date=datetime(2022,1,1), 
        schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=12), 
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1
        ) as dag:

    task_a = BashOperator(
        task_id="Inference_task_a",
        bash_command="/home/xfd/folder/env/bin/python3 compute.py",
        retries =1,

    )
```

When triggering the DAG, it failed.
[image: UI Airflow]

How can I know more about what causes the failure? I have seen that Airflow integrates with Sentry (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/logging-monitoring/errors.html?highlight=error). However, it might be overkill for simple dags like this one.

Ideally, I would like to get the output of the console command `/home/xfd/folder/env/bin/python3 compute.py` to debug what went wrong easily.
How can I track errors in Apache Airflow for a simple DAG like this one?

Comment: If you enter into the DAG and click on the task that is in red, you can then click on "Log" and there you will see the error

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: great, i'll turn the comment into an answer so that you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter into the DAG and click on the task that is in red, you can then click on "Log" and there you will see the error

[image]